# MS SQL Server 2012 null values when exporting data to flat files

Tags: sql-server, export

Trying to export data from tables into flat files, using the Import and Export Wizard in SQL Server 2012. I keep getting null values as empty, and I'd like them to remain as null. I know there should be an option, but I can't see it in any of the wizard steps. Can someone please tell me where I can set the export to keep null values?

Comment: `NULL` is the absence of a value - so exporting them as "nothing" seems quite fitting. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to export the data into a mySQL database